# ActiveVBProject.References Error in .FullPath

Tags: vba, excel

We have a module that checks for machine information for troubleshooting purposes. One of the sub modules checks each reference for breaks. However for a single reference, the Microsoft Office Soap Library 3.0 it halts on an error.

We can work around it, but I'm really interested to know what is causing this error. The reference is valid, not broken. The method of the reference object simply fails for this library.

> Method 'FullPath' of object 'Reference' failed

```
Private Sub getEachRef()

Dim ref As Variant
Dim strRef As String

'On Error Resume Next <- this allows the rest of the code to complete

For Each ref In Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References

    frmAbout.lst_About.AddItem "[Reference] " & ref.Description
    frmAbout.lst_About.List(frmAbout.lst_About.ListCount - 1, 1) = ref.FullPath <- error is here

    If ref.IsBroken = True Then
        frmAbout.lst_About.List(frmAbout.lst_About.ListCount - 1, 2) = "Broken Link"
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `The reference is valid, not broken.` How did you verify that? Can you manually check it?

Comment: The reference object has a method .isbroken which returns a boolean statement, in this case false. It also has a name value and a description. All of those are valid, it's only the .FullPath that returns an error. Additionally you may see your references in tools-> references in the dev window of the vba editor.

Comment: In the tools references window, can you see the full path in below frame?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes I can.

Comment: Hmm, I am confused. May I see a screenshot of that Tools|References window for `Microsoft Office Soap Library`?

Comment: Heading out for the day, I'll check this when I get back in tomorrow. But: The long and short is that on my machine I have a valid, complied and working reference. In the tools\references window the reference is valid and shows the path correctly. When that same reference is loaded as an object in vba, ref.name works, ref.isbroken works, ref.fullpath throws an error. This is important to me because it will be used by users who are far away and I can't always travel to their machine to see if the reference is valid in tools|references.

Comment: Hi @sten, did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm having the same issue with `OWC10` = `Microsoft Office XP Web Components` (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OFFOWC.DLL). --  `.IsBroken` is False, but `.FullPath` throws the runtime error. Thanks!

Comment: @Andre Unfortunately no. It moved out of scope and we dropped it. Which I despise. I have suspicions about how windows handles registry keys storing all this information after a recent (different) issue involving errors in a certain combination of Microsoft products with a certain combination of libraries with a certain combination of patches. Excel 2007+2010 with Office Lync installed... it's a mess.

Answer (score 2):

I run into this posting as I got the same error myself.

I've been able to trace the issue with your problem as follows:

- The Error Number returned is: -2147319779
- Code compiles without errors
- (as mentioned in the posting) The reference is valid, not broken
  (meaning that when you check your listed references, the reference(s)
  is (are) not Listed as 'Missing' or if checked through VBA, is not listed as 'Broken')
- I've read some other postings in other forums where even the code/VBA
  application (MsAccess) actually runs without problems in 'one' PC
  (PC 01) and returns the 'error' in another PC (PC 02)
- I've been able to replicate this phenomena myself.
- After comparing PC 01 with PC 02 you see that both PCs though may
  actually have the 'same' exact version of MsAccess/Excel installed +
  the same MsAccess (or Office) Service Pack installed but once you start to test each and everyone of the applied patches (this can be a
  long process), you will find that some Dlls have actually NOT been replaced/patched, updated.

In my case, those affected PCs (that will NOT run the Code, thus produce an error), each had a different cause (different, not properly updated dll), thus there is NOT a 'universal' 'replace the following dlls' to repair the problem.

That said however, there is a solution (so enough of trying to explain):

## 1st Solution (least invasive)

- Repair MsAccess/Office Installation.
- When completed, re-apply latest Service Pack + all Office Updates.

This solution in 'some pcs' resolved the issue, ie. VBA Code run without problems.

- If Repair MsAccess/Excel/Office Installation failed (due to Error
  2424, 2425, or repair fails), then, proceed to solution Nmr. 2 (no
  pun intended : D )

## 2nd Solution (middle group invasive)

- Uninstall MsOffice completely (including all updates, Service Packs, etc.)
- Will need a clean reboot after the uninstallation has completed.
- After the uninstall process has completed and the PC has been rebooted, then install MsOffice again (including all updates, Service Packs, etc.)

This solution actually worked on another sub-set of affected PCs I found.

- If uninstall of MsAccess/Excel/Office failed (due to the same
  previous Errors 2424, 2425, or repair fails, etc), then, proceed to
  solution Nmr. 3 (the nuclear option)

## 3rd Solution (nuclear option)

- Download and Install 'Microsoft Office 2010 FixIt Tool' (or the version that may apply to your situation) https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ocmsassetid=ha010357402&ctt=1&correlationid=8bfaf910-6d5f-4252-b5bb-0ed67d5d4349&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us
- Run Tool to remove MsOffice 2010 completely. Once completed (PC will
  need to be rebooted after the tool is finished with the cleanup/deinstallation)
- Reboot PC after MsOffice 2010 (or the version that may apply to your
  situation) removal has been completed (this step is very important)
- Install MsOffice/MsAccess/Excel 2010 (or the version that may apply to your situation) again.
- Install Language Packs (if needed).
- Install the latest Service Pack ie. Service Pack 1, Service Pack 2, etc.

This solution actually fixed the 3rd group of affected PCs I had. That said however, after a 'clean' install of MsOffice, some PCs, then got a different error:

> Ms Access/Excel Can't Open your previous application.

This error ONLY was found on PCs that had gone through the 3rd Option (though MsOffce and MsAccess 'seem' to work just fine and even the original 'Issue' as described in this posting was 'fixed' meaning that the code run without the Method 'FullPath' of Object Reference failed problem, then the 'new' problem was found as those 'latest' installs of MsOffice (2010 and later) seem to apply updates/service packs differently from commulative updates, vs. clean installs + latest updates/service packs.

## 4rth Option - Trapping the error

I'm using the same exact code as an example (see above) and insert an 'Error Trapping' Section as follows (I'm copying the entire code and pasting the completed module including the error trapping part):

```
Private Sub getEachRef()
On Error GoTo getEachRef_Err

Dim ref As Variant
Dim strRef As String

'On Error Resume Next <- this allows the rest of the code to complete

For Each ref In Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References

    frmAbout.lst_About.AddItem "[Reference] " & ref.Description
    frmAbout.lst_About.List(frmAbout.lst_About.ListCount - 1, 1) = ref.FullPath '<- error WAS here
getEachRef_Ressume01:
    If ref.IsBroken = True Then
        frmAbout.lst_About.List(frmAbout.lst_About.ListCount - 1, 2) = "Broken Link"
    End If

Next

getEachRef_Exit:
     Exit Sub

getEachRef_Err:
Select Case Err.Number
     Case -2147319779
    getEachRef_Ressume01
     Case Else
    MsgBox Err.Number & Err.Description
    Resume getEachRef_Exit
End Select
End Sub
```

This code sample allows the existing code to simply 'jump' over the 'error' and continue :).

In my case, after I had some PCs with Solution No. 1, others with No. 2 and No. 3.. on any new instances, since I implemented the above 'error trapping' into the module, no more errors have been produced anywhere else.

Just to be clear, with solution No. 4, the 'error' is NOT fixed but is simply bypassed and allowed the code to continue to execute the loop.

In my case, I added some more Code into the VBA to show the 'major' version and 'minor' version of the `ref.FullPath` in the above code that could not be shown (so that at least I can see what was bypassed by the code).

Comment: After posting my asnwer I saw that the entire answer was not formatted as I though. I've reposted the option number 4 Code for reference (all the previous 3 options are just step by step of different stages of repairing/reinstalling MSOffice.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub getEachRef()
On Error GoTo getEachRef_Err

Dim ref As Variant
Dim strRef As String

For Each ref In Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References

frmAbout.lst_About.AddItem "[Reference] " & ref.Description
frmAbout.lst_About.List(frmAbout.lst_About.ListCount - 1, 1) = ref.FullPath '<- error WAS here
getEachRef_Ressume01:
If ref.IsBroken = True Then
    frmAbout.lst_About.List(frmAbout.lst_About.ListCount - 1, 2) = "Broken Link"
End If

Next

getEachRef_Exit:
    Exit Sub

getEachRef_Err:
Select Case Err.Number
    Case -2147319779
        getEachRef_Ressume01
    Case Else
        MsgBox Err.Number & Err.Description
        Resume getEachRef_Exit
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: A little explanation might be helpful. What was the problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: That's a little unfair, he's clearly posting a follow-up to his original answer which is clearly workarounds to the original issue I posted... long ago. Sorry @H2CO3HCO3 but in fairness to showdev this doesn't really explain why it was happening which was my original question. An unsatisfied end, like most issues in VBA.

Comment: @showdev - the 'explanation' is actually clear from the original posting (I'm copying and  pasting it again): 'Method 'FullPath' of object 'Reference' failed'.

Comment: Once I run into the same error myself (as I posted) I posted the 4 ways I was able to get a resolution to the problem as posted by sten.
Just to clearify - my posting was not intending to explain 'why' the problem happened, but instead showing how I went around it to let the code run and continue. Thoguh the issue is still there, the code continues to run/execute, thus at least continues to execute 'bypassing' the error.